# Get Value from PHP Codeigniter to AJAX

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, ajax, codeigniter

I have a variable in php and i want to check in ajax if this variable value is word "RMA" or not.

```
If the variable value is "RMA" then my url ajax will change to

    url: "<?=site_url('equip_request/get_json_selected');?>",

else

url: "<?=site_url('spares/get_json_selected');?>",
```

Code:

```
$erf_header->purpose = "RMA"; // this is just an example variable and value
```

and this is my function in ajax

```
if ($.cookie("spare-items-loaded") == 1) {
                if ($.cookie("spare-items")) {

                    cookie_items = $.cookie("spare-items").split(",");

                    if (cookie_items.length > 0) {

                        var request = $.ajax({
                                url: "<?=site_url('spares/get_json_selected');?>",
                                type: "POST",
                                data: {
                                    ids: cookie_items.join(","),
                                },
                                dataType: "json",
                                success: function(data) {  

                                    var template = null;
                                    var source   = null;
                                    var result   = null;

                                    result   = jQuery.parseJSON(JSON.stringify(data));

                                    source   = $("#spare-loop-list").html();
                                    template = Handlebars.compile(source);

                                    $("#equipment-list").append(template(result));  

                                    cookie_items = jQuery.unique(cookie_items);             
                                    $("#total-spares").html(cookie_items.length);
                                }
                            });                 
                    }
                } else {
                    $("#equipment-container").hide();
                    $("#total-spares").html( 0 );               
                }
            }
```

Answer (score 1):

First we decide which URL we'll be sending `POST` data to.

```
$url = ''; //Initialize $url as global variable

if($var === "RMA"){
    $url = "site_url('equip_request/get_json_selected')";
}else{
    $url = "site_url('spares/get_json_selected')";
}
```

Then parse in the $url into the ajax request.

```
url: "<?=$url;?>",
```

On a sidenote, i'd be weary when using `<?=`, [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/200640/are-php-short-tags-acceptable-to-use) is why.

Additionally, by default, JS can only parse PHP if it's inline of a `.php` file, if it's not, see your options [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3862307/using-php-in-external-js).

Comment: you need to echo $url if it's in the javascript.

Comment: `<?=` is shorthand to echo.

Comment: yeah, <?=$url?> would do it.

Comment: so where i can i add my php variable in ajax? here is my variable
$erf_header->purpose = "RMA"

Comment: sorry i cannot get what you mean in this code im just new in ajax

Comment: This is where you'd add the PHP variable in AJAX -> `url: "<?=$url;?>",`